# Checking for file existence

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement

I have the following bat but it dosnt seem to work I want to check for a file name stoted in tom.txt, if it exists i want to do nothing, if however it dont exist i want to run the runme.bat

```
Echo Setting variable to file name
set FAT=<C:\tom.txt

ECHO Checking for file, if exists do nothing if not run bat...
if exists %FAT% (
end
)else(
 C:\runme.bat
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some minor mistakes, which, however, are the cause of your major difficulties.

1. You can read a line from a file with the `SET /P` command, not simply with `SET`:

   ```
   SET /P FAT=<C:\tom.txt
   ```
2. The keyword in the file existence check command is **`EXIST`**, not `EXISTS`

   ```
   IF EXIST …
   ```

   Also, if you only need to react to the file's *non*-existence, you can simply add `NOT`:

   ```
   IF NOT EXIST …
   ```

   So, the entire command might be like this:

   ```
   IF NOT EXIST %FAT% C:\runme.bat
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct syntax is

```
if exist %FAT% goto NORUN
C:\runme.bat
:NORUN
```

Notice "exist" vs "exists" in your code.  A couple other things to note:

1. File NUL exists in any directory on any drive, therefore checking
   for `C:\NUL` will always return true.
2. Checking for file existence
   does not always work correctly on network devices.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/65994 for a bit more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to do it all on one line like this:

```
IF NOT EXIST C:\tom.txt C:\runme.bat
```

There is no need for the variable unless you intend on using it again, it just means another line of code. As Aleks G and Andriy M said, you need to make sure the commands and parameters are spelt correctly.

Comment: Incorrect.  `tom.txt` is guaranteed to exist.  The file name we want is stored inside `tom.txt`.